# Why does calling submit cause jasmine to go into an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a test:

```
 describe('item-form', function(){
    var element;
    var elementScope;

    beforeEach(function(){
      element = $compile('<item-form></item-form>')($scope);
      $scope.$digest();
      elementScope = element.isolateScope();
    });


    it('should call $scope.addItem when form is submitted', function(){
      spyOn(elementScope, 'addItem');

      element.find('.item-form').submit();

      $scope.$digest();

      expect(elementScope.addItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

That tests a directive that renders this:

```
<form class="item-form" ng-submit="addItem()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="iName"  />
</form>
```

The directive is defined as:

```
.directive('itemForm', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'item-form.html',
            controller: 'ItemController',
            scope: {
                name: '@',
                addItem: '&'
            }
        };
    });
```

When jasmine launches a browser to test in, it shows all tests passing but constantly refreshes the page like it is in an infinite submit loop. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Before I also had a button for the form that would submit on click. This method worked fine, but I'd rather not have the button. I suppose I could hide the button, but I'd still like to understand the cause.

Comment: your directive is restricting to `E`lement, but you are using it as a comment - so i'm guessing the page is getting refereshed.

Comment: I removed the restriction and it still has the same behavior.

Comment: try setting it to `C`lass

Comment: What do you mean by you are using it as a comment? If I restrict to class, I won't be able to use the `<item-form>` tag anymore.

Comment: But your usage is a class

Comment: `element = $compile('<item-form></item-form>')($scope);`, also this works fine with manual testing.